How can a deno application access files (such as templates and assets) from the directory of a dependency?
Given a package which has some default templates or some default assets; how can a Deno application access and use such files?
Several example use cases:

An application which makes use of Nunjucks to render views and wants access to a library of templates provided by a package. For example, to take advantage of a component library, or to reuse templates which ensure consistent branding across multiple services.

An express application where some default assets from a package are statically served.

Common stylesheets which are reused across multiple services. As an example, perhaps .scss files which are imported into service specific .scss files.


Here are a couple of workarounds that I have currently found:

Create a script which copies these files into the application repository. This works but this adds some complexity and it's more difficult to maintain.

Execute deno with the --node-modules-dir switch which forces it to create a node_modules directory. It is possible to load such asset files from there. This deviates from the deno way of doing things though.

Somehow resolve paths to cached modules in the file system. This is similar to above but seems more fragile since the locations of module files could easily change in the future. There doesn't seem to be a built-in function to resolve paths to cached modules.



If the files are loaded by Deno (not by a 3rd party dependency like Nunjucks or SASS), you can simply fetch the file content:
const url = import.meta.resolve("./template.njk");
const res = await fetch(url);
const content = await res.text();

If the content is loaded by 3rd party dependencies, some of them allows to customize the file loader. This is how Lume loads Nunjucks templates (even remote files) https://github.com/lumeland/lume/blob/0588e1c73a6d666e220e4b5d3004fff80333b2bf/plugins/nunjucks.ts#L151-L189

How would this work if the template files are inside a dependency which your application is importing from. Eg. How would you get the import.meta.dirname of the dependency itself (rather than the application module).

I just edited the previous comment, because you can get the url of a dependency with import.meta.resolve().
About the external dependencies, it's the same way. import.meta.resolve can resolve any URL, even those mapped in the import map.
